# Is it possible to pass bundle keys to an app that is running in background (minimized)?

Tags: android, android-studio

Let's say that my app is closed, and another app starts my app. When my app start, i can getExtras sent by that app. But, when my app is already open and running in the background, and another app starts my app, i can't get does extras.

With "in background" i mean my app is minimized.

When my app gets active it fires the event onResume() on the activity but bundle is null.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `running in the background`? Which component exactly ? Activity , Service or Job ?

Comment: I think you applied the bundle code in onCreate method so when your app is not in background your activity onCreate invokes and you get the extras but when in background and you open your app again it will call onResume and not onCreate. I guess this is why you’re not getting extras from bundle. If not this issue then edit your question with detailed code.

Comment: @ADM its an activity. I have updated my question. thankyou

Comment: @KhushParmar the onResume() is called but bundle is null. I have updated my question. thankyou

Comment: asssign launchMode as `singleTop` to that Activity in manifest . You will get new Intent inside `onNewIntent()` method in Activity .